# What should be the value of image_user in template_user()?

Tags: python

I made a `PropertyGroup` in which I added an `image` as a `PointerProperty`

```
class Prop(PropertyGroup):
    image : PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Image)
```

I want to show that prop in the panel, but what should be the value of `image_user` in

`template_image(data, property, image_user, compact=False)`

Comment: So if you look at the bottom of the [docs page](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ImageUser.html#bpy.types.ImageUser) it looks like this template requires the image to be linked to something. It looks like it can be any type of image node, a camera, an object, or a texture. Basically you can't use it in a vacuum, this template must be used in coordination with either of these data structs. The current frame, cyclic, etc. properties are not stored on the image itself, but on the link between the image and the other struct

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear in the documentation what the purpose of `image_user` is, but based on a [search in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=image_user&check_keywords=yes&area=default#) it must be one of these:

```
bpy.types.CameraBackgroundImage.image_user
bpy.types.ImageTexture.image_user
bpy.types.Object.image_user
bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexEnvironment.image_user
bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage.image_user
bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.image_user
bpy.types.TextureNodeImage.image_user
```

It depends on what you are trying to do and which [`bpy.types.ImageUser`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ImageUser.html) you want to reference to:

> **bpy.types.ImageUser**
> Parameters defining how an Image data-block is used by another
> data-block

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but as example, I created an image `bpy.data.images['Untitled']` and a texture `bpy.data.textures[0]` and passed `bpy.data.textures[0].image_user` as parameter.

Comment: I want to show the image when I select the image in the property